# Function to achieve "Element does not have this child"?

Tags: xquery

I want to retrieve the documents in a collection which satisfy that a given element does not have a specific child element. For example, from the two "documents" below, I want to select doc 2, since it has the element child, but doc 1, since it does not.

*Doc 1*:

```
<doc>
 <element>
  <child/>
 </element>
</doc>
```

*Doc2*:

```
<doc>
 <element>
  <other-child/>
 </element>
</doc>
```

I tried doing this:

```
for $item in collection('/db/collection')
where not($item//child)
return $item
```

However, this does not work for some reason. I also tried various combinations of `exists`, sequence functions etc, but couldn't get the result I want.

To clarify, the `not($item//child)` test does not seem to do what I think it'd do. The above query returns every document in my collection, wether it has the element or not.
The inverse works, however:

```
for $item in collection('/db/collection')
where $item//child
return $item
```

This query returns exactly those documents which have the child element.

What gives?

Comment: This is really weird. If you use `count($item//child)` instead, what output do you get - are there any with 0?

Comment: Oh, and by the way, which XQuery implementation is used?

Comment: I've checked this using Saxon 9 (using a plain sequence of `<doc>` nodes rather than `collection`, however), and I see the expected results, not what you describe. It would seem that either your actual XML is more complicated, or your query isn't as written, or your implementation is buggy and/or non-conformant.

Comment: See my answer below. Thanks for your assistance anyways!  
(btw, is "correct behaviour" in these circumstances to post an answer myself and mark it as correct answer? Not having it answered brings up that little notification suggesting it'd be bountied...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be a bug in eXist's XQuery engine (1.2.6) when using namespaced xml documents, since it works on documents without a namespace, and on the latest svn snapshot.
Bummer.

Answer (score 4):

I think you need to use both not() and exists() to achieve your desired results. So, I think you want to do something like:

```
for $item in collection('/db/collection') return
    if (not(exists($item//child))) then $item
    else ()
```

About your namespace issue: if your document uses a namespace, then you should have the proper namespace declaration in your XQuery statement, like `declare namespace ns="some_uri";`

Hope this helps.

-tjw

Answer (score 0):

To get around the bug, how about this for the moment:

```
for $item in collection('/db/collection') 
return 
  if ($item//child) then
    $item
  else 
    ()
```